# how to combine odometry and imu data?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ... i want to combine roomba580  odometry and imu data .
irobot roomba wheels encoder cant count in backward  & increase backward move with forward moving.becase of this odometry problem i want to combine odometry and imu data !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33868/how-to-combine-odometry-and-imu-data?/) by [reza shahabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/2100/reza-shahabian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [reza shahabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/2100/reza-shahabian/) on 2012-05-16**:
tnx ryan .
i think this way is correct.but i faced with this error when i want to run "turtlebot_node" ...
'failed to find rosdep daemontools for package turtlebot nod on os:ubuntu version :marverick'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest taking a look at the [base TurtleBot stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot). Specifically, [turtlebot_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node) publishes encoder and IMU data, and an instance of [robot_pose_ekf](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) launched by "minimal.launch" within [turtlebot_bringup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_bringup) combines the two.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-11-07**:
i do not find anything about ekf in turtlebot packages !